# 3D Plot with a colormap - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a 3D surface plot showing `voltage` vs. `temp` vs. `power`, and to scale the colour of each point to another array of values, known as `bifurWidth`.

Below is my code.

Problems with my code:

1. I cannot make my code run for a 'bifurWidth' `numpy.ndarray` generated using `loadtxt`. The error in this case is `Color array must be two-dimensional`. However it *does* run if I generate a dummy set of bifurWidth values using `np.arange()`. Why does this happen when both are `numpy.ndarray`s?
2. I have no idea how to get this working, with a legend visible, for a 3D surface plot.

Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
from glob import glob
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

import os

fs = 22

# Import data.
voltage = np.loadtxt('NonLorentzianData.txt',usecols=[0])
power = np.loadtxt('NonLorentzianData.txt',usecols=[1])
bifurWidth = arange(len(voltage))#np.loadtxt('LorentzianData.txt',usecols=[3])
temp = np.loadtxt('NonLorentzianData.txt',usecols=[4])
path = np.loadtxt('NonLorentzianData.txt',usecols=[5],dtype='S16')
c = np.abs(bifurWidth)

#Plot a 3D pot showing Temperature/Voltage/Power and intensity of colour showing bifurcation size.
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
cmhot = get_cmap("hot")
ax.scatter(voltage,temp,power,bifurWidth,s=35,c=c,cmap=cmhot)
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature (mK)',fontsize=fs)
ax.set_xlabel('Voltage (V)',fontsize=fs)
ax.set_zlabel('Power (dB)',fontsize=fs)
ax.set_title('Locating bifurcations.',fontsize=fs)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.set_size_inches(25,15)
fig.savefig('TEST.PNG',dpi=300)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you say you want to make a surface plot, but in your code you  make a scatter plot. Based on the rest of your problem description I assume you want to make a scatter plot.

When I look at the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#scatter-plots) of the `scatterplot` function I see the following definition:

```
Axes3D.scatter(xs, ys, zs=0, zdir=u'z', s=20, c=u'b', depthshade=True, *args, **kwargs)
```

You call it as:

```
ax.scatter(voltage,temp,power,bifurWidth,s=35,c=c,cmap=cmhot)
```

This means that the fourth formal parameter, `zdir`, will be called with the value of `bifurWidth`. This is not what you want, you want to use the default value of `zdir` and to use the absolute value of `bifurWidth` as the color (the second thing you already accomplish by setting `c=c`).

Therefore, just remove the `bifurWidth` parameter like so:

```
ax.scatter(voltage,temp,power,s=35,c=c,cmap=cmhot)
```

This should get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505105/add-a-legend-in-a-3d-scatterplot-with-scatter-in-matplotlib) question 3D scatter plots won't work with legend so you need to make a dummy plot that isn't displayed to create the legend. Here's an example related based on your question that adds a legend to a 3d scatter plot:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

# Fake data
(voltage, temp) = np.meshgrid(range(10), range(10))
power1 = np.random.rand(10,10)
power2 = np.random.rand(10,10)
bifurWidth1 = 100*np.random.rand(10.,10.)
bifurWidth2 = np.random.rand(10.,10.)

# Plot data
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
cm1 = get_cmap("Blues")
cm2 = get_cmap("Reds")
ax.scatter(voltage, temp, power1, c = bifurWidth1, s=35,  marker = 'o', cmap = cm1)
ax.scatter(voltage, temp, power2, c = bifurWidth2, s=35, marker = "^", cmap = cm2)

# Make legend
scatter1_proxy = matplotlib.lines.Line2D([0],[0], linestyle="none", c=cm1(128), marker = 'o')
scatter2_proxy = matplotlib.lines.Line2D([0],[0], linestyle="none", c=cm2(128), marker = '^')
ax.legend([scatter1_proxy, scatter2_proxy], ['label1', 'label2'], numpoints = 1)

# Label axes
fs = 12
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature (mK)',fontsize=fs)
ax.set_xlabel('Voltage (V)',fontsize=fs)
ax.set_zlabel('Power (dB)',fontsize=fs)
ax.set_title('Locating bifurcations.',fontsize=fs)

plt.show()
```

[image: 3d scatter plot with legend]