# 3D plots and legends issue when plotting some dimensions of PCA

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following data and labels I am transforming through PCA. 
The labels are only 0 or 1.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

fields = ["Occupancy", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Light", "CO2", "HumidityRatio", "NSM", "WeekStatus"]
df = pd.read_csv('datatraining-updated.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields, sep=',') 
#Get the output from pandas as a numpy matrix
final_data=df.values
#Data
X = final_data[:,1:8]  
#Labels
y = final_data[:,0]
#Normalize features
X_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
#Apply PCA on them
pca = PCA(n_components=7).fit(X_scaled)
#Transform them with PCA
X_reduced = pca.transform(X_scaled)
```

Then, I just want to show, in a 3D graph, the 3 PCA features with highest variance, I can find them as follows

```
#Show variable importance
importance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
print('Explained variation per principal component: 
{}'.format(importance))
```

After that, I want to plot only the top-3 highest variance features. So, I previously select them in the code below

```
X_reduced=X_reduced[:, [0, 4, 5]]
```

Ok, here is my problem: I can plot them without the legend. When I try to plot them using the following code

```
# Create plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
colors = ("red", "gray")

for data, color, group in zip(X_reduced, colors, y):
    dim1,dim2,dim3=data
    ax.scatter(dim1, dim2, dim3, c=color, edgecolors='none',  
    label=group)

plt.title('Matplot 3d scatter plot')
plt.legend(y)
plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
plot_data-3d-pca.py:56: UserWarning: Requested projection is different from current axis projection, creating new axis with requested projection.
  ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
plot_data-3d-pca.py:56: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
  ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py", line 307, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py", line 76, in draw
    self._render_figure(allocation.width, allocation.height)
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py", line 20, in _render_figure
    backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 388, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1709, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 135, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 292, in draw
    reverse=True)):
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 291, in <lambda>
    key=lambda col: col.do_3d_projection(renderer),
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 545, in do_3d_projection
    ecs = (_zalpha(self._edgecolor3d, vzs) if self._depthshade else
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 847, in _zalpha
    rgba = np.broadcast_to(mcolors.to_rgba_array(colors), (len(zs), 4))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in broadcast_to
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 182, in broadcast_to
    return _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok=subok, readonly=True)
  File "/home/unica-server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 127, in _broadcast_to
    op_flags=['readonly'], itershape=shape, order='C')
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (0,4) and requested shape (1,4)
```

My y's shape is (8143,) and my X_reduced's shape is (8143,3)

What is my mistake?

**EDIT:** The data I am using can be found [here](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~ra023169/datatraining-updated.csv)

Comment: Why not `ax.legend()` without handing over y as handle?

Comment: could you be more specific? ax.legend() after the for loop doesnt work (same error), even plt.legend() gives me the same error

Comment: Can you give an example of `final_data` so we can run your code?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity please check my edit. I also updated the code so you can simply copy and paste

Comment: What's 'datatraining-updated.csv'? If you could just create a small dataframe with hard-coded values, we'd be able to copy and paste your code and have it run

Comment: datatraining-updated.csv is the text file where the data comes from (there is a link at the end of the post where you can download it). Just copy and paste the code and you will get the same error as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first warning `Requested projection is different from current axis projection` 
is because you are trying to change the projection of an axis after its creation with `ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')` but you cannot. Set the projection at creation instead.

To fix the second error, replace `edgecolors='none'` by `edgecolors=None`.

The following corrected code works for me.

```py
# Create plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d') # set projection at creation of axis
# ax = fig.gca(projection='3d') # you cannot change the projection after creation
colors = ("red", "gray")

for data, color, group in zip(X_reduced, colors, y):
    dim1,dim2,dim3=data
    # replace 'none' by None
    ax.scatter(dim1, dim2, dim3, c=color, edgecolors=None, label=group) 

plt.title('Matplot 3d scatter plot')
plt.legend(y)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT :** Above is my answer to what I understood of the original question. Below is a looped version of mad's own answer.

```py
class_values = [0, 1]
labels = ['Empty', 'Full']

n_class = len(class_values)
# allocate lists
index_class = [None] * n_class
X_reduced_class = [None] * n_class

for i, class_i in enumerate(class_values) :

    # get where are the 0s and 1s labels
    index_class[i] = np.where(np.isin(y, class_i))
    # get reduced PCA for each label
    X_reduced_class[i] = X_reduced[index_class[i]]

colors = ['blue', 'red']

# To getter a better understanding of interaction of the dimensions
# plot the first three PCA dimensions
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 6))
ax = Axes3D(fig, elev=-150, azim=110)

ids_plot = [0, 4, 5]

for i in range(n_class) : 

    # get the three interesting columns
    data  = X_reduced_class[i][:, ids_plot]

    ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2], c=colors[i], edgecolor='k', s=40, label=labels[i])

ax.set_title("Data Visualization with 3 highest variance dimensions with PCA")
ax.set_xlabel("1st eigenvector")
ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.set_ylabel("2nd eigenvector")
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.set_zlabel("3rd eigenvector")
ax.w_zaxis.set_ticklabels([])

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: This code gives me just one simple graph with few points. Please check my solution below and, if you could do the same with a for loop I can mark your answer as the one that will help me for sure.

Comment: @mad I edited to add a looped version of your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error in a different way.

I did not know that, for each label, I had to do a different scatterplot. Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505105/add-a-legend-in-a-3d-scatterplot-with-scatter-in-matplotlib) I found the answer.

My solution was first to separate the labels and data from one class, and then do the same for the other class. Finally, I plot them separately with different scatterplots. So, firstly I identify the different labels (I have only two labels, 0 or 1) and their data (their corresponding Xs).

```
#Get where are the 0s and 1s labels
index_class1 = np.where(np.isin(y, 0))
index_class2 = np.where(np.isin(y, 1))

#Get reduced PCA for each label
X_reducedclass1=X_reduced[index_class1][:]
X_reducedclass2=X_reduced[index_class2][:]
```

Then, I will plot each PCA reduced vectors from each class in different scatterplots

```
colors = ['blue', 'red']

# To getter a better understanding of interaction of the dimensions
# plot the first three PCA dimensions
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 6))
ax = Axes3D(fig, elev=-150, azim=110)
scatter1=ax.scatter(X_reducedclass1[:, 0], X_reducedclass1[:, 4], X_reducedclass1[:, 5], c=colors[0], cmap=plt.cm.Set1, edgecolor='k', s=40)
scatter2=ax.scatter(X_reducedclass2[:, 0], X_reducedclass2[:, 4], X_reducedclass2[:, 5], c=colors[1], cmap=plt.cm.Set1, edgecolor='k', s=40)

ax.set_title("Data Visualization with 3 highest variance dimensions with PCA")
ax.set_xlabel("1st eigenvector")
ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.set_ylabel("2nd eigenvector")
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.set_zlabel("3rd eigenvector")
ax.w_zaxis.set_ticklabels([])

#ax.legend(np.unique(y))
ax.legend([scatter1, scatter2], ['Empty', 'Full'], loc="upper right")

plt.show()
```

Which gives me this beautiful image

[image]

Of course, such a code can be simplified with a for loop too (altough I have no idea how to do that).